# How do I access a component's state data outside of the component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules

I am using the npm library react-flippy for a flash cards Q/A app. I have an array of Q/A objects as a reducer and a random number as component state. When the user clicks the Next button, a random number is generated which determines the next Q/A object to populate the front and back of the card.

The issue I am having is if the BackSide (answer) of the card is visible when the Next button is clicked, the card does not revert back to FrontSide (question) for the next Q/A information, it stays on the BackSide revealing the answer to the question.

I have looked through the react-flippy module to try and find the variable/state that determines if the card is flipped or not (I am assuming its a boolean called isFlipped). I need to reset this variable back to false in the randomQuestion function thats called by the Next button. How do I find the variable/state doing this in the flippy-react module and how do I access it outside of the Flippy element?

The Github for react-flippy: https://github.com/sbayd/react-flippy

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import '../styles/style.css';
import Flippy, { FrontSide, BackSide } from 'react-flippy';

class MenuCards extends React.Component{
    state = {
       randomNumber: 0
    }

    randomQuestion = (arry=[]) => {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * arry.length);
        this.setState({randomNumber: num});
        //-- Need to reset isFlipped back to false here...
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className='ui container'>
                <div style={{ margin: '2em' }} className='ui one column stackable center aligned page grid'>
                    <div style={{ margin: '2em' }} className='ui one column stackable center aligned page grid'>
                        <h1 className='ui header'>Food Menu Flash Cards</h1>
                        <div className='column twelve wide'>
                            <Flippy flipOnHover={false} flipOnClick={true} flipDirection='horizontal' ref={(r) => this.flippy = r}>
                                <FrontSide style={{ backgroundColor: 'maroon' }} id='question'>
                                    <h2 id='text' className='ui header'>Question</h2>
                                    <p id='text'>{ this.props.questionAnswer[this.state.randomNumber].question }</p>
                                </FrontSide>
                                <BackSide style={{ backgroundColor: 'maroon' }} id='answer'>
                                    <h2 id='text' className='ui header'>Answer</h2>
                                    <p id='text'>{ this.props.questionAnswer[this.state.randomNumber].answer }</p>
                                </BackSide>
                            </Flippy>
                            <button id='next-button' className='fluid ui button' onClick={() => this.randomQuestion(this.props.questionAnswer)}>Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        questionAnswer: state.questionAnswer
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MenuCards);
```

Answer (score 0):

This `isFlipped` is a prop your `Flippy` accepts, meaning you can set the card to be flipped or not from outside the component (but, according to the official documentation, your `flipOnHover` and ’flipOnClick’ wouldn't work). It doesn't have its internal state.

Read some more about React state and props - these are the fundamentals.